# returning a lambda function in clisp, then evaluating it

Tags: lisp, lambda, common-lisp

Suppose I have this wonderful function foo

```
[92]> (defun foo () (lambda() 42))
FOO
[93]> (foo)
#<FUNCTION :LAMBDA NIL 42>
[94]>
```

Now, suppose I want to actually *use* foo and return 42.

How do I do that? I've been scrounging around google and I can't seem to come up with the correct syntax.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want the [`FUNCALL`](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_funcall.html) function:

```
* (defun foo () (lambda () 42))
FOO
* (funcall (foo))
42
```

Answer (score 6):

The relevant terms here are "*Lisp-1*" and "*Lisp-2*".

Your attempt at calling would work in a Lisp-1 like e.g. Scheme or Clojure.
Common Lisp is a Lisp-2 however which roughly means that variable names and function names are separate.

So, in order to call the function bound to a variable you either need to use the special forms `funcall` or `apply` as others have pointed out or set the function value of the symbol `foo` rather than the variable value.

The former basically takes the variable value of the symbol, assumes/checks that value is a function and then calls the function (with whatever arguments you passed to `funcall`/`apply`.

You don't really want to do the latter as that is quite silly in all but very specialised cases, but for completness sake this is roughly how you'd do it:

```
CL-USER> (setf (symbol-function 'foo) (lambda () 42))
#<FUNCTION (LAMBDA ()) {C43DCFD}>
CL-USER> (foo)
42
```

You should also want to look into the `labels` and `flet` special forms (which are commonly used) - there you actually *do* use the latter methods (these forms create a temporary function binding for symbols).

So your problem would there look like this:

```
(flet ((foo () 
         42))
  (foo))
```

i.e. here you temporarily bind the *function* value of the symbol `foo` to the function returning 42.  Within that temporary context you can then call `(foo)` like regular global functions.

Answer (score 3):

Your function `foo` returns a [function](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_f.htm#function). Use the [`funcall`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_funcal.htm) function to apply a function to arguments, even if the argument set is empty.

Here you can see that `foo` returns a value of type [`function`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_fn.htm):

```
CL-USER> (let ((f (foo)))
           (type-of f))
FUNCTION
CL-USER> (let ((f (foo)))
           (funcall f))
42
CL-USER> (type-of (foo))
FUNCTION
CL-USER> (funcall (foo))
42
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option besides FUNCALL is APPLY:

`(apply (foo) nil)`

FUNCALL is the idiomatic way here, but you'll need APPLY when you have a list of parameters.